# Run a function and check if another function is already executed using C

Tags: c, function, conditional-statements, call

Using C, I want to run one function based on another. I need to check if a specific function is executed. if yes, then I want this function to execute as well when called, otherwise not.

I am reading some text from a file. in the first function, I want to read them and print them. now in the second function, I need a condition, that if the first function is executed, then run this as well. otherwise, do nothing.

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

**NOTE:** THIS IS THE COMPLETE SOLUTION. AFTER THE QUESTION WAS ANSWERED.

My code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int already_run = 0;

void Reading_Function(FILE **rf)
{

already_run = 1;
   *rf=fopen("file.txt","r");

   if(rf==NULL)
   {
       printf("Error in file openning.");
       return 0;
   }

    char first [120];
    fscanf(*rf,"%s",first);
    printf("Value: %s", first);

}

// this is the second function

void Second_Function(FILE *rf)
{
if (already_run)
{
    char second [50];
    fscanf(rf,"%s",second);
    printf("Value: %s", second);
}
else

    return;


}

int main()
{



  char t;
  FILE *rf;
  while(scanf("%c", &t)==1)
    {
        switch(t)
        {

        case 'f' :
        Reading_Function(&rf);

        break;

        case 's' :
          Second_Function(rf);

        break;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Let me know if the question is not clear. Thanks.

Comment: Set a flag. If flag set, don't do it again.

Comment: should I set that flag outside of both functions? and how to call it in each?

Comment: You should *define* the flag outside of the functions, but *set* it either inside the function, or in your `main()` routine after calling that function. As in `if (!ReadingDone) { ReadingFunction(rf); ReadingDone = 1; }` or something similar where `int ReadingDone = 0;` is established near the beginning of `main()`.

Comment: the first function runs, and it prints a value as well. but when I enter `s` from the keyboard, it does not print anything. in which case should I put that flag, which you told about above?

Comment: Instead of clunky uses of `scanf` like this, stick with `getc` or something simple. Also look into using `argv` instead of user input, that way you can call your executable with the same arguments repeatedly, easily, which makes testing easier and more predictable.

Comment: Sir, look at the second_function. I did not call any file there. I just want the second function to work only if the first function is already executed. if not, then nothing. the flag still does not work. Maybe because I put it in the wrong place.

Comment: Can you update your question with the revised `main()` function?

Comment: updated main. now both functions works. but I do not want second_function, to work if Reading_funciton is not called.

Comment: Read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/). It is relevant for the title of your question (and it is not about C programming)

Comment: You have to gate each call of that `Reading_Function()`, which means you could embed a `static` variable.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch really?

Comment: Exactly, Thank you tadman. i solved my problem. as per @nemequ 's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments above already answer your question.  Just to keep things simple, here is what the code would look like:

```
static int already_run = 0;

void Reading_Function(FILE *rf) {
  already_run = 1;
  // ...
}

void Second_Function(FILE *rf) {
  if (already_run) {
    // ...
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

That said, if what you're trying to do is only have people call `Second_Function` but have the stuff in `First_Function` run the first time `Second_Function` is called, a better way to do this is:

```
void Second_Function(FILE *rf) {
  static int already_run = 0;

  if (!already_run) {
    already_run = 1;

    // Initialization code goes here.  You can even split it out
    // into a second function if you want, in which case you would
    // just invoke that function here.
  }

  // ...
}
```

That way you don't have any global variables to worry about.

Of course, both methods break down if your code is multi-threaded; in that case, you should use a once (like [`pthread_once_t`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_once), [`call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/call_once), [`InitOnceExecuteOnce`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683493(v=vs.85).aspx), or [something](https://github.com/nemequ/portable-snippets/tree/master/once) which abstracts the different APIs away for portability).

Comment: I used both of your ways, unfortunately, none of them work. Please have a look at my code, there might be a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thank You. the second method works now. I will update the code.